# Sitecore: Session Started Pipeline

Tags: sitecore

I need to detect when a new session is started and I'm unable to locate a pipeline or processor for it. Ironically, I've found the sessionEnd pipeline!

The only other way I can seem to make it work is using Global.aspx to hook the session start event.

Comment: What about the `createVisit` pipeline? I know it's not exactly what you're looking for but maybe it's good enough?

Comment: let me give it a look

Comment: @webber have you found out what works best for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own processor to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline with the following code:

```csharp
if (Session["exist"] == null)
{
    // your code that should be executed on session start.

    Session["exist"] = true;
}
```

Comment: this is not a clean way to do it as httpRequestBegin  will be invoked for every resource

Comment: hm, createVisit, for example, works in a similar way:
renderLayout -> StartAnalytics -> StartTracking -> initializeTracker -> CreateVisit... And somewhere inside is check equivalent to Session["exist"] == null that checks if analytics is initialized for this session. And it is invoked for every resource that have layout.

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you're looking for [here](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/a-sitecore-8-request-from-beginning-to.html)

Depending on what you're looking for maybe the startTracking pipeline is what you want.